# custom header of UICollectionView with xib failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
let identifier = "collection"
var collectionView:UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadNav()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 8
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth / 2 - 12, 150)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 64, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight - 64), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "StoreCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HeadCollectionVIew", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "head")

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let head = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "head", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    return head
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth, 280)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoreCollectionViewCell


    return cell
}



import UIKit

class HeadCollectionVIew: UICollectionReusableView {

@IBOutlet weak var test: UIView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```

}

Here's all my code. I'm trying to add an empty view in the xib named HeadCollectionView. When I run my application, it crashes, but when I delete the empty view, it works.

Im getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<NSObject 0x7fc98e089190> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test.'
```

Comment: The interface Builder was created with the .swift which has the same name